# Checkbox parameter passing to check for checked values only

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am unsure how to setup the following to check for checked items, i.e.:

```
function selectorToArray(pSelector){
  var lArray = [];
  $("input[name='f19']:checked").each(function(){
      lArray.push($(this).val());
  });
  return lArray;  
};

var lf19 = [];
lf19 = selectorToArray("input[name=f19]");
```

Basically within the function selectorToArray(pSelector), I do not want to use:

```
$("input[name='f19']:checked").each(function(){
```

as this is hardcoded; instead I want to use `$(pSelector:checked).each(function(){` but this doesn't work.

I am looking for the correct syntax for only looking for checked values based on pSelector passed in as part of my .each function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to concatenate the passed the value,

```
$(pSelector + ":checked")
```

The above code will be evaluated as,

```
$("input[name=f19]:checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use,

```
$(pSelector + ":checked").map(function () {
     return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

Comment: Hey Pilot, will check out the map function - thanks.

Comment: @tonsils if you use `map` and `get` then you wont need to define unnecessary varible `lArray = [];`, you can simply return above value..`.get()` will give you the array of checked values. So much simple and pretty..